# what is wrong with this sql statement

Tags: sql, mysql

What is wrong with this statement?

```
CREATE TABLE `CSV_DB`.`bavaria_test` (
`Schule`,
`Stasse`,
`Ort`,
`Tel`,
`Schulgliederung`,
`Integrationsklasse`,
`Besonderheit`,
`Homepage`,
`E-Mail`,
`Schulnummer`,)
 ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' `Stasse`, `Ort`, `Tel`,
>   `Schulgliederung`,
>   `Integrationsklasse`, `Besonde` at
>   line 2

Comment: for the sake of helping other people with your question (those who answer and those who have the same question) you should change the column names from german to english :)

Comment: hello Samuel  -  you are right! - i will do this!

Comment: The problem is all your field names are in some kind of crazy gibberish. ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using MySQL because of `ENGINE = MYISAM`:

You must read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html). You are forgetting to specify the types of each column and you have a extra comma here `'Schulnummer',)`.

Comment: hello Murilo - mille grazie! Your very supportive

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the data types for the columns.  Also, you don't need those back-tick quotes:

```
CREATE TABLE bavaria_test (
    Schule int,
    Stasse varchar(100),
    -- etc.
)
```

Comment: You may not *need* backticks, but they are always a good idea.

Comment: hallo TehShrike, many many thanks for the hint! This is a great hint! I am very very thankful! Great Support here! It is overwhelming!! greetings to you martin

Answer (score 3):

The columns are missing data types.

The last column has a extra comma at the end

Answer (score 2):

Remove the trailing comma after `Schulnummer`. That comma tells it there will be another column in the list, and there is not.

Answer (score 2):

You've defined your column names but not given the columns a data type.

For example, Schule could be defined like:

`Schule` varchar(50)

which would indicate that the column is a "string" that can hold up to 50 characters.

Comment: hi there - many thanks - i ve missed this by mistake!! Thx - greetings!